adding a "save as" commandbutton in a slide (powerpoint)
I'm trying to add a commandbutton "save as" at the end of a powerpoint slideshow.
The code (partially in french, sorry) :
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileFilter As String
    Dim InitialFileName As String

  ' Définir le nom du fichier par défaut
  InitialFileName = "MaPrésentation.pptx"

  ' Définir les types de fichiers pour la boîte de dialogue "Enregistrer sous"
  FileFilter = "Fichiers PowerPoint (*.pptx), *.pptx"

  ' Ouvrir la boîte de dialogue "Enregistrer sous"
  FilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName, FileFilter, 1, "Enregistrer sous")

End Sub

Then, in debug :
.GetSaveAsFilename "error of compilation / method or data member not found"

What's wrong ?
Thanks

The good code (for powerpoint) is :
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
    
    ' Créer une boîte de dialogue de sauvegarde
    Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    
    ' Définir le nom du fichier par défaut
    dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = "MaPrésentation.pptx"
    
    ' Définir le filtre pour les types de fichiers
    dlgSaveAs.FilterIndex = 1 ' Choix du premier filtre (par défaut: .pptx)
    
    ' Ouvrir la boîte de dialogue "Enregistrer sous"
    If dlgSaveAs.Show = -1 Then
        ' Récupérer le chemin du fichier sélectionné
        FilePath = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
        
        ' Enregistrer la présentation à l'emplacement choisi
        ActivePresentation.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath, FileFormat:=ppSaveAsDefault
        MsgBox "Fichier enregistré avec succès à l'emplacement : " & FilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Enregistrement annulé."
    End If
End Sub


This is the reason of why is wrong
Because in PowerPoint VBA, Application.GetSaveAsFilename isn't a standard method. PowerPoint uses FileDialog instead of GetSaveAsFilename. So this answer that is implementing FileDialog should be a good ide
